# references to css and javascript from html don't work only on localhost

Tags: css, gruntjs

I am automatically inserting references to css and js files into html head with help of grunt-link-html plugin, but when viewing the page on http://localhost:9000/ files are not found ('Cannot GET'). The styles and scripts are referenced relatively and are showing when viewing the file by double-clicking from harddrive:

```
<!-- begin:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../deploy/css/myproject.min.css">
<!-- end:css -->

<!-- begin:js -->
<script src="../deploy/js/myproject.min.js"></script>
<!-- end:js -->
```

I'm new to Grunt, what am I missing? Thanks for any help

project structure:

```
MyProject
    _build
        node_modules
        Gruntfile.js
        package.json
    deploy
        css
            myproject.min.css
        js
            myproject.min.js
    src
        css
            myproject.css
        js
            myproject.js

        index.html
```

extracts from the gruntfile:

```
express: {
  all: {
    options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: "0.0.0.0",
    bases: ['C:/Users/user1/MyProject/src']
    }
  }
},
open: {
  all: {
    path: 'http://localhost:<%= express.all.options.port%>',
    app: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
  }
},
link_html: {
  your_target: {
    jsFiles: ['../deploy/js/portfolio.min.js'],
    cssFiles: ['../deploy/css/portfolio.min.css'],
    targetHtml: ['../src/index.html'],
    options: {
      cwd: '../deploy'
    }
  }
}

grunt.registerTask('server', ['connect', 'express', 'open', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `..` at the beginning of the CSS & JS file paths are correct for Grunt if run from `_build` subdir, but not for the page, because `index.html` is at the project root directory.

I would move the Grunt stuff from `_build` to project's root folder and remove the `..` from `Gruntfile.js`, too.

After a Grunt rerun it should work, then.

Comment: thanks! I couldn't move grunt to the project root as I didn't want to reinstall all the plugins at the root level, but this gave me an idea to move index.html to the root (it was in src subfolder before). after updating express bases path and link_html path it works

Comment: Reinstall should be no problem, if you are using `--save-dev`. See [GruntJS manual](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-grunt-and-gruntplugins). I am glad its working - have you considered accepting my answer?

Comment: I clicked the up arrow next to the answers on this topic, but it says I can't leave feedback until I reach 15 reputation points myself :/ thanks for your help though, I'll come back to leave you feedback once I get to those 15 points :)

Comment: I am not saying you have to do this, but you should be able to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark below the arrows (see [stackoverflow's tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with these spesific grunt modules, but I am guessing the problem is that you define the "bases" of express.all as your src folder, and not your "myProject" folder.

So when your server wants to serve you files (like your css and js) it only looks in the /src folder, where you dont have a "../deploy/" folder.

Try changing your bases to ['C:/Users/user1/MyProject/deploy'] and your jsFiles and cssFiles, remove the "../deploy", they should now reside in the "/js" and "/css" folders.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks, this seems to work with a little restructuring. I changed express bases to C:/Users/user1/MyProject, moved .html to the root of the project and changed path to it in for link_html, which is now targetHtml: ['../index.html'],

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought or two: 
1.Try using the same separator in all links, as there is a difference between "\" and "/" in some environnements (browsers vs editor vs os vs anything else).
2. (dumb question ?!) Are you sure you have read/write/execute rights on the files you are accessing ?

Comment: thank you, it's a very helpful thought about the slashes, I'll keep it in mind